# what s the meaning of 'THE USS COLE IS A STATE OF THE ART DESTROYER'

Tags: american-english, sentence

THE USS COLE IS A STATE OF THE ART DESTROYER, DEPLOYED IN THE PERSIAN GULF.

I know the every meaning of each word, but when i read it i cant get the message in it.

Comment: Don't say get to mean understand. Not everything is a joke, least of all destroyers.

Comment: A destroyer is a type of war ship.

Answer (score 2):

"State of the art" should really be hyphenated in that sentence, as in "state-of-the-art destroyer". "State of the art" is a common phrase (being used as an adjective here) that basically means having the best current technology.